# Yup: string not defined

Tags: javascript, yup

I've started to work with Yup recently and there is this schema in my project that I need to change a parameter from string to an object {string, string}

how it was (is working):

```
exports.schema = yup.object().shape({
 destination: yup.string().required('required msg'),
 .....
})
```

how I want to be:

```
exports.schema = yup.object().shape({
destination: yup.object().shape({
    name: string().required('required msg'),
    id: string().default(null).nullable()
  }).required('required msg'),
....
})
```

But after I change the object i've been geting this error:

> ReferenceError: string is not defined

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to use `yup.` before the `string()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a yup before string(). Example

```
name: yup.string().required('required msg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed yup before string

```
exports.schema = yup.object().shape({
destination: yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required('required msg'),
    id: yup.string().default(null).nullable()
  }).required('required msg'),
....
})
```